# How to fix phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I install xampp server in vm and i accessed to it from another machine,
for xampp server it work but i have this problem in **phpmyadmin** when i navigate to https://ip/phpmyadmin:

```
Erreur
MySQL a répondu: Documentation
#2002 - Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
Le serveur ne répond pas (ou l'interface de connexion vers le serveur MySQL local n'est pas correctement configurée).
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Can you post the error message in English? SO is English oriented. Sadly there isn't a french version of the site

Comment: The response says that the client (phpmyadmin) cannot connect to the server: 1) Did you make sure that your server is running? 2) Did you double-check whether IP-adress and port in your phpmyadmin configuration file are correct? 3) Did you connect your server with any other clients (for example mysqlworkbench), and did this work? 4) Did you try to _telnet <server's ip adress> 3306_? (Should work both on windows and unixoids.)

Comment: i configure config.inc.php and i change  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost',  localhost to my adress ip but it always the same problem

Comment: Does phpMyAdmin work on the local machine (the one running XAMPP) when looked at as http://localhost/phpmyadmin ? First get it working locally, then try to connect from the remote web browser to the server's phpMyAdmin instance.